# Two If statements using index match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

`=IFERROR(IF(I33<120,INDEX('Cost Lookup'!$E$3:$E$12*I33,MATCH(Data!J33,'Cost Lookup'!$C$3:$C$12,0))),IF(I33>120,INDEX('Cost Lookup'!$F$3:$F$12*I33,MATCH(Data!J33,'Cost Lookup'!$C$3:$C$12,0)),""))`

Above is the formula that I am using.  If the cell's value is less than 120, I want to look in the E column for a value to multiply.  But, if the cell's value is greater than 120, I want to look in the F column for a value to multiply.  I am continuously getting a False whenever the number is greater than 120 which means it's not going to the second part of the formula.  Please advise..

Comment: What happens if `I33` is equal to `120`?

Answer (score 2):

You have some `)` in the wrong place:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(I33<120,INDEX('Cost Lookup'!$E$3:$E$12*I33,MATCH(Data!J33,'Cost Lookup'!$C$3:$C$12,0)),     
    IF(I33>=120,INDEX('Cost Lookup'!$F$3:$F$12*I33,MATCH(Data!J33,'Cost Lookup'!$C$3:$C$12,0)))),"")
```

Comment: It still returns 'FALSE' if the number is equal to or greater than 120

Comment: @Tina you did not specify `equals`  see edit.

Comment: Scott,I needed to put >=120, along with moving the ) as you suggested.  Thanks for the response!